# How to translate the memory content of IAS computer into Assembly language

Tags: assembly, machine-code, ias

Given the following memory contents

```
Address    | Contents
08A        | 010FA210FB
08B        | 010FA0F08D
08C        | 020FA210FB
```

The assembly code is:

[image: Assembly Code]

My question is, how are the contents translated into the assembly code.  What separates the opcode from the operands in the memory contents here?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ias, but normally the opcode is the first byte of each instruction.  The CPU (and disassembler software) know not to try to interpret the rest of the bytes of an instruction as opcodes, because they know how long an instruction is.

Comment: You need to read up on assemblers. In the days of IAS, they were called auto-coders.

Answer (score 2):

The instructions are stored two at a time in blocks of 10 bytes. The first two bytes of each set of five are the opcode in hex; so for example on the first set of contents, 010FA and 210FB correspond to 2 different instructions. The first two bytes in binary are the opcode, so for the first instruction, 00000001 corresponds to LOAD, and then it loads the hex value from the rest of the instruction, in this case 0FA.

Answer (score 0):

A visual aid to [Sam B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7497672/sam-b)'s answer

The instructions are stored two at a time in blocks of 10 bytes. The first two bytes of each set of five are the opcode in hex;
[image: IAS Memory Format]

IAS Instruction Set table
[image: IAS Instruction Set]

*Reference: Computer Organization and Architecture 10th edition (William Stallings)*